# jQuery Tablesorter File Size in Rails App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml, tablesorter

So all of my columns sort without issue, except for my Media column which displays quotas for file size limits (GB, TB, etc.) I suspect the Rails NumberHelper `number_to_human_size` isn't playing nicely with tablesorter. Anyone have an idea how to get it to sort, while utilizing the NumberHelper?

[image]

_table.html.haml

```
%table#myTable.tablesorter
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Name
      %th.right Per Month
      %th.right Members
      %th.right Additional
      %th.right Media
      %th.right Subscriptions

  - if @plans.any?
    %tbody
      - @plans.each do |plan|
        %tr
          %td
            = link_to admin_plan_path(plan) do
              = plan.name
          %td.right
            = "$ #{plan.base_price_in_cents / 100}"
          %td.right
            = plan.included_users
          %td.right
            = "$ #{plan.price_in_cents / 100}"
          %td.right
            = number_to_human_size(plan.media_data_quota) || '&infin;'.html_safe
          %td.right
            = link_to organizations_admin_plan_path(plan) do
              = plan.subscriptions.count
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make file sizes sort properly, you'll need a parser to convert "GB" and "TB", etc, into sortable numbers.

There is a [metric parser](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-metric.js) available on my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) - [demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-metric.html) which converts both metric & binary values to make sorting work.

To use it, load the parser file, then add a `sorter-metric` and `data-metric-name` attribute:

```
<th class="sorter-metric" data-metric-name="b|byte">Media</th>
```

I haven't tested it, but if you are using the original tablesorter, this parser should still work. If that is the case, the sorter class name won't work, so you'll need to set the `headers` option:

```
headers: {
    0 : { sorter: 'metric' }
}
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to js. Can you explain to me how to load the parser file? I d/l it, put it in my vendor folder, required it in my application.js and called on it in the view: `%th.right.sorter-metric{"data-metric-name" => "b|byte"} Media` with no success. TIA.

Comment: The parser files are not set up to work with AMD/UMD; so you might have to add it manually; unless you make a [custom build](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki/Customize#custom-build) which creates a file that includes the core, selected widgets & selected parsers all wrapped in UMD code.